# Manga about a demon king or villain, who wants revenge against the heroine, but is too weak, so he just stays with her and cleans her house

Tags: story-identification, manga, demons

The title of the Japanese manga that I'm looking for:

I don't really remember, but it's about like a demon king or villain of some sort who manages to escape from being imprisoned by the heroine. So, he went to take his revenge, but her reincarnation isn't a hero and he is also extremely weak, so instead, he just stays with her and cleans her house, claiming he will eat her one day.

I can't remember the color of her hair. I think I remember that although the heroine wasn't a hero per se she was indeed abnormally strong. The demon king appeared not in human form but as a cute creature, (not sure if it was a kitten) but he was capable of switching forms just not often

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the heroine's hair?

Comment: I was thinking *Hataraku Maō-sama!* at first, but the heroine isn't reincarnated.

Comment: Just to confirm, the heroine is powerful from the start, and doesn't just pull out a holy sword or anything? Does the demon king appear as a regular human male, or is he trapped in another form? Is he a baby or a kitten? Finally, do you remember when you read this?

Comment: I can't remember the color of her hair since, I think it was black and white. But yes, I think I remember that although the heroine wasn't a hero persay she was indeed abnormally strong and yes the demon king appeared not in human form but a cute creature, (not sure if it was a kitten) but he was capable of switching forms just not often? Maybe

Comment: Does the house cleaning include anything like doing tests in her place? The cat manga I was thinking of is Kyuuketsu Yuugi / Vampire Game. No claims of  eating yet, nor actual housework. But the other details are a decent fit. Any idea if this is it before I read more?

Answer (score 1):

This may be *[Mugen Spiral](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/mugen-spiral)*

> Yayoi, a spunky high school girl, has inherited spiritual powers from her mother, and she uses these powers to protect people. During a fight with the devil Ura, Yayoi's power turns the devil into a black kitten. Now, even though **Ura doesn't hide his desire to "eat" Yayoi's power when he gets the chance, they develop an interesting relationship: the two begin living together**, and Yayoi takes her new feline "friend" on her adventures.

It matches several points from the question. A demon appears and attacks Yayoi, the protagonist, but she has special powers and uses them to seal the demon into a cat form. The cat still wants to eat her to gain her spiritual powers.

[image: Talking cat wants to eat people]

Yayoi is strong enough to do this with a spiritual item, but it described as being significantly weaker than her ancestors. The demon-cat can transform back into a human shape if Yayoi allows it.

What doesn't match is the housework; I was only skimming this but I didn't see any housework involved. The demon instead protects her from other demons that similarly want to eat her (stating "she's my prey"). The demon is weak while in cat form but seems to still have all his powers when in human form, so I'm not sure if he's "extremely weak". Finally, I don't believe the demon was sealed by her ancestors at all, and he's not taking revenge for that. He just wants to eat her. She's also not reincarnated, just a descendant of a long line of mystics, but I think that bit is reasonably close.